# How to return value from function in color?

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce, colors, product-variations

I have this function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 
'grey_out_variations_when_is_backorder', 10, 2 );
function grey_out_variations_when_is_backorder( $grey_out, $variation ) {

if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() && $variation->backorders_require_notification() )
    $grey_out = false;

return $grey_out; // Here want to return value in some color?


}
```

So want to know how to return value in some color? Function is for gray out the products that is not in Stock in WooCommerce shop. Currently only back gray out selection in some gray color. Some tip ,or advice how to get back value in color?

Current State:

[image]

I want to show like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the frontend is disabling the grayed out select>option items (disabled="disabled"), then you can apply some CSS to those items:

```
select option:disabled {
    color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: This is CSS that control that part with colors:

`.variations .select-wrapper .sbOptions li span.sbDisabled, .variations .sbHolder .sbOptions li span.sbDisabled {
CSS code..
}
    `

Comment: Also what if i have more different function that return data? How to handle different colors in that functions ? See my question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168656/colour-in-backorder-products-dropdown-based-on-stock-in-woocommerce